# How can I map objects in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

Let's assume that I have in my POST method three fields - `field1`, `field2`, `field3` however in POST method `field2` and `field3` should have the same value during adding to the database. So there is no need to add for instance `field2=2`, `field3=2` manually. I could add only  `field1=1`, `field2=2` and then `field3=2` will be added to this body automatically and finally whole 3 fields will be added to the database.  I wonder how it should be done in most optimal way? Should it be done in view? I try in the way shown below.

views.py:

```
class UserObject(GenericAPIView):

    def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return ObjectPostSerializer
        return ObjectSerializer

    def post(self, request, user_id):

        serializer = ObjectPostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user_id=user_id)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ObjectPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ObjectPostSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for key in self.fields:
            self.fields['field3'].required = False

    class Meta:

        model=Object
        field3 = model.field2

        fields = ('__all__')
```

Comment: If `field2` and `field3` will always have the same value in the database, why are both fields needed?  Couldn't you do away with one of them?  But to answer the question, a good way to do it would be to write `serializer.save()` such that it ignores the value of `field3` and uses the value of `field2` for both database columns.

Comment: @JohnGordon Because in the future only field2 will be updating, field3 means initial value. Can you take a look on code in updated question? How can I solve it?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Django object serializers so I can't comment on the specifics, but it seems like you've got the right idea.

Comment: @JohnGordon But field3 is not added to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can use simple logic, exclude `field3` from post serializer, and set it on `save` method of model

in serializer:

```
class ObjectPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Object
        exclude = ('field3', )
```

in models:

```
class Object(model.Model):
    # YOU FIELDS DECLARE HERE

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.field3 = self.field2
        super(Object, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: But in other methods like `PUT` or `GET` I need to have whole model. Only in `POST` I would like to use one field less.

Comment: why name of your seriaizer is `PostSerializer`?

Comment: Because for POST method I tried to create separated serializer - `ObjectPostSerializer`. For other methods there is `ObjectSerializer`.

Comment: and now you want to change the logic and use one serializer for all case?

Comment: No, I think that it would be easier to have separated serializer for POST and another serializer for other methods. Because in `ObjectPostSerializer` I can set `self.fields['field3'].required = False` etc. but in other methods I need to add this field.

Comment: i don't understand why the solution is not suitable?

Comment: Because field3 is not added to the database. How can I assign the value of field2 to field3 and add to the database?

Comment: did you override save method?

Comment: No, I didn't. Can you show me how it should be done?

Comment: look in the answer, please.

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: I noticed that when I use DRF documentation I get error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'method'` and this is associated with this line `if self.request.method == 'POST':` Do you have an idea how can I solve it?

Comment: sorry but i'm not have idea, may be better write more details with code and full error stack, in new question.